# Class for JPA criteria entity with _ appended to className doesn't exist

Tags: java, jpa, playframework-2.0, criteria-api

I'm trying to convert a simple Play/JPA query to use the criteria API.  Below isn't even the query I'm trying to convert; this one's even *simpler* -- just trying to get *something* to succeed to begin with.

All the examples I've been finding online expect you to be able to use a class that has _ appended to the class name, much like what I've seen hibernate queries do to table name aliases in the generated SQL.  However, I can't get my code to compile this way since there is no class: ExtendedHaulTrain_ (there is however ExtendedHaulTrain)

Is there some kind of annotation I need to add to the ExtendedHaulTrain class?  Perhaps I have not been reading deeply enough but the examples I've found so far don't address the issue of the class with the underbar appended.

Here's my code that fails to compile on the last line, specifically on ExtendedHaulTrain_

```
Query query = JPA.em().createQuery("select DISTINCT(x.trnType) from ExtendedHaulTrain x");
List<String> trainTypes = query.getResultList();

//as criteria query
CriteriaBuilder cb = JPA.em().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<ExtendedHaulTrain> q = cb.createQuery(ExtendedHaulTrain.class);
Root<ExtendedHaulTrain> xhtRoot = q.from(ExtendedHaulTrain.class);
q.select(xhtRoot.get(ExtendedHaulTrain_.trnType)).distinct(true);
```

Comment: Guess I found some information here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/metamodel.html  But the idea that I have to create even more classes is rather daunting; maybe there's a way to do what I'm trying to acheive *without* metamodel classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the MetaModel classes(they end with '_') you can always use the attribute name in form of a string as refrence.

```
q.select(xhtRoot.get("trynType")).distinct(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in my comment there is a notion of a meta-model class I'd rather avoid.  So below is how I converted my existing query to use the criteria API.  Again, this is just to get a success under my belt; I'm probably not going to replace *this* query.  Rather I have another more complex query, for which I intend to use the Criteria API; this was just to get some familiarity with the Criteria API -- there will probably be more questions to follow!

```
/*
Query query = JPA.em().createQuery("select DISTINCT(x.trnType) from ExtendedHaulTrain x");
List<String> trainTypes = query.getResultList();
*/

CriteriaBuilder cb = JPA.em().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery(ExtendedHaulTrain.class);
Root root = cq.from(ExtendedHaulTrain.class);
cq.select(root.get("trnType")).distinct(true);
List<String> trainTypes = JPA.em().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you do not like these meta-models but this is actually a very useful thing, which keeps your code on the safe side of type-safety (believe me, once you begin to write more queries, you will see the advantage). And the advantage is: you can generate them automatically with the so called meta-model generators (which are annotation processing tools). Hibernate has for example something one [generator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/jpamodelgen.html). In Eclipse it is very easy to generate them. Also in Maven it is easy. I recommend to use them.

---

UPDATE

Type Safety means actually beside not having to write `xhtRoot.get("trynType")` also that you work with correct join types. Do not forget, that compared to NamedQueries, CriteriaQueries are not checked on deployment. This means, if you remove or use the wrong type in the generic part of a join result (WrongOwner below)

```
Join<WrongOwner, Address> address = cq.join(Pet_.owners).join(Owner_.addresses);
```

you will know that on compile time.

Comment: I'll consider them in the future but for now I'm trying to get a project done quickly without adding too many artifacts, and even using the Criteria API was one thing I had to get agreement to use.  I guess the type-safety is in not having to write `xhtRoot.get("trynType")`.  I've always just thought you should be able to pass a (partially) populated instance of your class in, I'd be interested in the rationale for a "meta" model.